# Movable widgets over video in website

Tags: html, video

I am still very much in the planning phase on this but here is the basic idea of what I want to do. I also have not done much/any web development in the past few years so I am a little out of the loop on what will/wont work.

I want to have a video playing essentially on a background layer with various widgets on top of it. The widgets will all be fairly simple HTML based text and maybe a few images. The widget also need to be movable (eg. I need to be able to drag and drop the widgets to move them). Finally I would really like it to work on a tablet (iPad or Android).

Am I going to need to use flash or silverlight for something like this? I would rather not because I know that makes it hard to get tablets working. I know HTML5 is supposed to be the new hotness but I don't really have a good idea of its capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash or Silverlight will rule out tablets (the iPad anyway), not just make them hard.

I'd start with [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) it supports easily making elements moveable.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it might be just the right thing for this prototype.